# Where is `getParent()` method on `$parent` in installer class coming from?

Tags: joomla-api, jinstaller

The Joomla! MVC development docs for writing an intall script gives an [example com_helloWorldInstallerScript](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file). That class has an `install()` method, with this example:

`$parent->getParent()->setRedirectURL('index.php?option=com_helloworld');`

Where is the `getParent()` method coming from? Can anyone point me to documentation for it? The docblock in the example installer class says "This class will be called by Joomla!'s installer", but the `getParent()` method is not on [Installer](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Installer.Installer.html), [JAdapter](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JAdapter.html) (extended by Installer), or [CMSObject](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Object.CMSObject.html) (not sure if docs are out-of-date, as JAdapter says it extends JObject, or if that dependency is removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JAdapterInstance](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JAdapterInstance.html). In 4.0 it's moved to InstallerAdapter.

Comment: Thanks, Sharky. Too bad the API documentation doesn't show interfaces implemented, next time I'll dig into the source. I'd upvote you but don't have enough points to do so :) Any idea why they designed the API this way (i.e. with a `getParent()` method on the interface)? I'm curious what the design process was, to improve (or know what to avoid) in my own API design efforts.